# Dynamically change style variables conditionally in Gatsby

Tags: css, sass, gatsby

I am porting an app that uses handlebars, scss, express, jquery and mongodb to Gatsby. I have a _variables.scss file that is imported into all my scss modules. I would like to adjust it conditionally depending on what database we are using. If we are using say X database, then the variables for certain colors will change for that database, if we use Y database, then we will use the appropriate colors for that database, etc. Checking what database we are using is not important at the moment, I would just like to find a solution for changing these variables or changing the variable file that will be used.

My variables file looks like this.

```css
/*
* Theme
*/
$main-color: rgb(222, 2, 2);
$main-color-darker: rgb(209, 0, 0);
$secondary-color: rgb(2, 19, 133);
$secondary-color-darker: rgb(220, 48, 5);
$main-background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
$root-background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
$background-color-light: rgb(254, 254, 254);
$navbar-background-color: $main-color;
$footer-background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
$background-color-darken-subtle: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
$dark-overlay: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
$card-name: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
$box-shadow-banner: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
$box-shadow-card: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
$text-shadow: 1px 1px 0.15rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
$border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
$border-main-color: 1px solid $main-color;
$border-radius: 5px;
```

Which is imported into my scss modules like this:

```css
@import "_variables.scss";

/***
 * Navbar
 * -
 */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: $navbar-background-color;
}
```

I have considered passing the variables as a props object to the components like this

```js
//In a layout component

const variables = {
  maincolor: "blue",
}

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar variables={variables} />
      //...more code


//in the navbar component
const Navbar = props => {
  return (
    <nav
      style={{ backgroundColor: props.variables.maincolor }}
      className={styles["navbar"]}
    >
    //...more code
```

I suppose I could do a check to see what database Im using and use an if statement to adjust the variables object and its keys and values based on the database being used, but then I would have to go through every element in every component and add inline css wherever a scss variable is used, so this doesnt seem like a feasible option.

I have also considered having multiple variable files,

```
_variablesDB1.scss
_variablesDB2.scss
_variablesDB3.scss
```

then doing a check somewhere for the database used, and in gatsby-node.config using fs.rename to rename the variable file we want to use to "_variables.scss".The problem is how would I then rename that variable file back to say _variablesDB1, it may be possible but my gut tells me its probably a bad practice and not a good solution.

The only other solution that comes to mind is porting all the scss to css in js with something like styled components, then having a variables object and changing it based on the DB used or some kind of condition, possibly with state. I have been researching this for the past few days, and cant come up with a solution. I appreciate your time, thank you.

Comment: At what time do you know which styles to load? Build or runtime? Can you explain this in more details?

Comment: On compile time we'll load the right database and the styles. I was considering using Gatsby themes for this. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

you can use "css variables" instead of scss variables, and override its values at runtime. Biggest advantage is, it doesn't require compilation.

//theme1

```
[data-theme='theme1']
--main-color: rgb(222, 2, 2);
--main-color-darker: rgb(209, 0, 0);
```

//theme2

```
[data-theme='theme2']
--main-color: rgb(0, 0, 8);
--main-color-darker: rgb(103, 0, 0);
```

And in the component which is going to use the style. Based on the currently chosen theme, the css variables will update themselves.

```
background-color: var(--main-color);
```